# CSS Background Issues

Tags: html, css, background

I am trying to get my background to behave the same way as http://www.gamestop.com's background but everything I have read and tried doesn't work right.

Here is the CSS I currently have and I feel like it just needs to be tweaked a little to make it respond the way I want it to:

```
html{
    background: url('../images/fbg.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-color:#000;
}
```

It is supposed to be fixed at the top of the page, centered, and all overflow should be hidden on the image to where if you were to zoom out it would simply show more of the image on the sides but remain fixed at the top in the same spot. I also would like to make it so that this background is click-able like a link and haven't been able to find anything about that either..

The site that it is going on is http://www.hackersarchive.com/beta.

Comment: Are you aware that your backround weights 2.7 MB ?

Comment: Not sure what your refering to when you say you want the background to behave like `www.gamestop.com`. Can you clarify? This is the image they use http://cdn1.kongcdn.com/assets/files/0001/1664/destiny-GSskin.jpg

Comment: The image from gamestop is actually not fixed at all it is just `no-repeat top center`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all of the replies! I figured it out & it was right in front of my face! Thank you for everyone who did answer the question for me as well!

Here is the correct code I was looking for:

```
html{
    background: url('../images/fbg.png') no-repeat center top;
    background-color:#000;
}
```

Simple issue that was more of a hassle than it should have been.